# configure the public ip jboss AS7

Tags: configuration, jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss AS7 as my application server on ubuntu server. When I try to access my application using the localhost or local ip address, it works fine. But I need to run my jboss as7 using an "public ip". but when I give a public ip and try to run my application, it doesn't work.

How do I configure the application so that it runs on public ip? is there any configuration files where I should mention the public ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out [AdminGuide-Interfaces](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Interfaces) there are several ways to do it.

The easiest is to pass the bind address to the start script

```
./bin/standalone.sh -b 1.2.3.4
```

but you can also configure it statically

```
<interfaces>
    <!-- … -->
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="1.2.3.4">
    </interface>
    <!-- … -->
</interfaces>
```